# Remove input border from under overlapping label CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, sass

I have an input and a label that look like this currently. What I would like to do is make the line from under the label disappear. I would just like to know what css I would have to add to the existing design to make that work.

[image]

Comment: Try `border: none` on the input element, or if you just want to remove the top border, `border-top: none`.

Comment: At least show us your code so we can know what you're working on and what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can remove borders on input elements with `border: none` or specific borders with `border-top: none`, et cetera.

```css
input {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test tester">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
input:focus {
    outline:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set backgreound-color as input/background background-color for the label. With this solution, only the border part behind the label will disappear.